# how to properly save and retrieve threads into/fom mongodb database in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, sockets

I have a local network consisting one server and multiple client devices. The devices are configured in such a way that they are permanently trying to connect to a server listening to a well defined port, say port number 4000 (so on the client side everything is already set).

This is stepwise how the system works:
- At startup, the server accepts all the client devices trying to connect(one client socket is created for each connection).
- The server creates a thread in which further communication with the client will later take place when necessary.
- The server saves the created thread into mongodb database with the associated sockets.
-This will be done for all the connected client devices

Later on, when there will be a command to be sent to a chosen client device (through a GUI),
-The server side should first connect to the database and retrieve the thread created for that particular client, with the associated client socket.
-Then the server should start the retrieved thread.
-And finally, in the started thread an input/output stream should be created in order to write the command to the client socket and read the answer (which will be further processed).

This is how I implemented the multithreaded server class :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;
import com.mongodb.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MultiThreadedServer {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // variables's declaration
    int portNumber = 4000;
    boolean  listening = true;
    QuoteServerThread thr = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    MongoClient mongoClient = null;

    try {
        //Creates a server socket listening on port 4000    
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);

        //set the socket timeout
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);

        while (listening ) {
            //Accepts a client
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            // Creates thread 
            thr = new ClientServerThread(clientSocket);            

            //Access the database and saves the thread
            mongoClient = new MongoClient();
            DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "testingDB" );
            DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("testData");

            //This is how I though of saving the thread in the DB. I don't know if its the proper way though
            // I would also like ot save it with the associate client socket for later use
            BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
            doc.put("threadID", thr.getId());
            collection.insert(doc);                 
        }


        //Here I would like to access the database and and get the thread with the associated client socket and start the thread

        // I don't know how to do it !!!!


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
        mongoClient.close();
        serverSocket.close();
}
```

This is the thread class :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ClientServerThread extends Thread {
private  Socket socket = null;

public ClientServerThread(Socket socket) {
    super("ClientServerThread");
    this.socket = socket;
}

@Override
public void run() { 
    try{

        // Get the client socket, create input and output streams and send command to the client device.
        .........
        .........

    }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace(); 
    }


      } 
 }
```

My problem is that I don't know :
-The proper way to save a created thread into mongodb database with the associated client socket.
-How to retrieve the threads from database .

I am really stuck here and I would appreciate if anyone could help me on this.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: This question is a complete misunderstanding of threads and how they work.  You can't persist them.

Comment: You can't store a thread or a socket in a database any more than you can store a car in one. Only information can be stored in a database. There's probably a good way to do whatever it is you are trying to do, but it's not going to involve storing threads or sockets in databases.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Sorry, but  I am not that experienced in that. But having read a bit about threads, I also came to that conclusion that I cannot persist them. The purpose of posting this question was also  to know if my understanding was right.  Yes now I understand/know it is not possible.  But Is there anyway to do this otherwise ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't save threads or sockets into a database.

Even in the best case you would only be saving some kind of a representation of them (thread name, socket address and port). You wouldn't be able to load them and have them be "live" again.

Comment: Well, you're only describing your attempted solution. You should be describing the actual problem you're trying to solve (what are the clients? what are the commands that the server gets?). With the least amount of modification the architecture would remain the same, but instead the thread/socket would just remain idle instead of being persisted.

Comment: The clients are (signal) transmitters with an Ethernet interface.First of all, the data about them (IP address, position (long, lat), status, etc) are stored in the database and they can only be modified or retrieved by sending commands (SET and GET commands described in the xmitter manual) via a GUI (there is a form with a field where the command can entered and submitted).The position of the Xmitters (for example in a building) are displayed on maps (as markers) and I can click on whichever xmitter I want and send a command to it. All this is working fine with only one transmitter connected.

Comment: Here is the situation, I have thousands of xmitters and I would like to be able to send the command only to the transmitter on which I have clicked (meaning to one specified IP address among say thousands of them). What do think is the best way of doing that?

Comment: So the transmitters connect somewhere and wait for commands? Sounds a bit backwards. I'd expect the transmitters to wait for someone to connect to and command them.

Comment: I would say the transmitters are ready for a communication and I can connect to them whenever we want. But whenever the server is  started ( i.e. when I click on one marker on the map in order to send a command to that particular transmitter ) ,  after  ".accept() "  , a random transmitter among  thousands might connect  and it might not be the one I wish to command. So I am looking for a way to check if the connected transmitter is the one I want to command before sending the command.

Comment: I'm still unclear on why a transmitter would connect somewhere just to wait for commands. I can imagine you connecting to a transmitter to give commands, or the transmitter connecting somewhere to transfer data by itself. The scenario you describe is a weird hybrid, which sounds very wrong.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Maybe I am not  describing it well. Please suppose you have thousands of transmitters (each of them having an IP address) in a network and you only want to connect and give commands to only one of them. Please how would you go about that ?

Comment: I would keep track of their IP addresses and any other information needed, then connect to them when necessary. This is the basic approach, used for example by your web browser. You connect to the website, the websites don't all connect to you.

Comment: yeah, what you've just described is very logical. And I can have the IP addresses and all the needed information from the database ( no problem with that). But now I am bit confused because from what I've learnt, when implementing a server side application to  establish a communicate with a client in java, the IP address of the client is not mentioned/used (please correct me if I got it wrong ). So I don't know how the server would  connect to a specific IP ( client) address among many?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding that a server application can only accept connections. It's perfectly possible (and common) for a server to act as a client for another server. You don't need to (just) wait for connections just because your component is named "server".